# .Net: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON - Ajax call to upload files

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing and contact form where user will be able to attach files. In order to prepare the file for sending I am using ajax call which is calling method and moving the file to temp folder. When the img is successfully uploaded to the temp folder returning

```
return Json(new { allowedFile = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This way I will show the uploaded img name and give opportunity to the user to delete it if he wants to

The ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: dataActionAttribute,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("success");
        if (response.allowedFile) {
            alert("success from if");
            Some more code here....

        }
        else if (response.maxFileExceeded) {
            alert("to many files");
            Some more code here....

        }
        else {
            alert("file extencion not alowed")
            Some more code here....

        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        succes = false;
        var err = "Error found: " + " status: " + status + ", p3: " + p3 + ", p4: " + p4;
        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] === "{")
            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

The img is uploading successfuly but when the ajax returns the response is throwing exception...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 20
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.error (<anonymous>:136:28)
at c (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:34474)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:35427)
at l (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:96612)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.1.min.js:2:99442)
```

I tried to change the jquery vervsions but still the same

The exact response is but cant find from where is taking those 'null' values
[image]

the error when debuging

```
Error found:  status: parsererror, p3: SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 20, p4: undefined
```

[image]

at the same time the xhr response

[image]
[image]

Comment: `err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;`  - xhr.responseText probably isn't *only* JSON - try debugging `xhr.responseText` to see what it actually is.

Comment: What is the actual text returned? (E.g., from the devtools Network panel.) In particular, what's at index 20? It sounds like some middleware (or whatever they're called in ASP.net MVC) is incorrectly adding to the response after the JSON, since the JSON for that sans whitespace (which would be normal) is `{"allowedFile":true}` -- 20 chars long. So that matches up with what the error is saying.

Comment: *"The exact response is but cant find from where is taking those 'null' values"* Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 It's not at all hard to copy and paste from the Network panel.

Comment: But separately: We can't help you based on just the information above, even if you posted that as text. Clearly, you have something in your server code that's adding those characters at the end of the response. We don't have access to that server code, you'll need to do the debugging.

Comment: How can I debug the server side code. Indeed in the console response I can see it is adding those null in the response text

Comment: We identified *where* the error occurred - no need to add screenshots of the same error

Comment: In older versions of browsers (*cough* IE ofc) it would fail to read the response if it wasn't at least x amount of characters (256 if I recall) - so there will be something in your C# MVC that *pads* *every* output so that it's at least the minimum length - it *should* pad it with spaces, but who knows what nefarious code you have running.

Comment: Look in your UI's FilterConfig / RegisterGlobalFilters